# Is it possible to reuse materials in threejs editor

Tags: three.js

A designer have created a **json scene file** of 16 really simple objects, I'm trying to make the file smaller in size, and one way of doing it is to use the same material for all the meshes inside of it.

I looked almost everywhere for a way to do it in https://threejs.org/editor/ and I can not see any option to do that.

what's the best way to do it?

Comment: Have you considered compressing the json? I think you can achieve quite a bit of savings in a file that’s describing 3D data.

Answer (score 2):

For some time the editor provides a material browser that allows to assign existing materials in the scene. You find the respective UI in the `PROJECT` tab, section `MATERIALS`. Just select and object, then the desired material from the list and then click on the `ASSIGN` button.

`three.js R112`

Comment: thank you I totally missed that! I'll try to fix it now.

Comment: Please accept/upvote the answer if it was useful to you.